# Where to submit bugs for SQL Management Studio 18.x?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

Where do we go to submit bugs for SQL Management Studio 18.x ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately, the link within SSMS is currently broken:

[image: SSMS Help Menu]

This should be fixed for the next release.

In the meantime, it is possible to submit feedback at [aka.ms/sqlfeedback](https://aka.ms/sqlfeedback). This shortlink should always point to the correct page.

It covers all SQL Server items, including Azure Data Studio... if anyone actually uses it.